# Populate objective-c array from JSON

Tags: php, objective-c, json

I have a php file which is taking values from mysql. I want to put all the values of my php file into xcode arrays. My php file returns data in 3 columns: "ID", "Name", and "Message". How can I load this data into my xcode array?

My php output is:

```
[{"id":"7","Name":"Benedict","Message":"IT Support Engineer"},{"id":"6","Name":"Naushad","Message":"IT Support"}]
```

I want to put the data from each column into different arrays, i.e. IDs should be in the *myid* array, names should be in the *myname* array, and messages should be in the *mymessage* array.

I would really appreciate your help as I have been trying to solve this problem for the last week.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

JSONKit (https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using iOS 5 or above you can use the inbuilt JSON serializer.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010946